# Port to open for miNifi

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I have a Nifi cluster on one server and miNifi on another server.

I have to open port on both sides to allow communication (HTTP).

On the Nifi cluster, I opened 8443 as it the https port where the UI is running.

On the miNifi, I do not know which ports I need to open, it seems to me that a random port is picked-up at the start of miNifi instance. If I am right, is there a way to set this port? Else how can I proceed?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

@Pdeuxa The MiNiFi flow should route to a named Input Port via a Remote Process Group at the bottom of the MiniFi Flow.  You are not actually setting an input port number.  In older versions of NiFi, that input port will need to be on the main canvas.  In newer version it can be in any deeper process groups too.  The MiNiFi flow should be built on the same Nifi instance that holds the Input Port.   Then when you route the bottom of the MiNiFi flow to the Remote Process Group in your MiNiFiFlow you will be able to select that Input Port.  Like this:

[image]

Here are some screen shot samples showing MiNiFi Flow:

[image]
[image]

And you can find the template on my GitHub:

https://github.com/steven-dfheinz/NiFi-Templates/blob/master/MiNiFi_Tail_Logs_to_NiFi_to_HDFS_Demo.xml

Comment: Steven, thank you for you answer ! I totally understand the input port within the nifi interface, and how to set up S2S.
Sorry if I was not clear, my question question was more about the 'physical' port of the computer where miNifi is installed. Minifi and Nifi are installed on two differents networks, thus I want to open the right port on each computer/server. minifihost:port <--> nifihost:port(8443)

I have the port 8443 for my Nifi cluster, but I do not get throught which port miNifi communicates (for HTTP and RAW transfer protocol); my networks skills are some how limited.

Comment: Nio problem, just make sure you can get from minifi to nifi on the main nifi port.  You should notice that port in the remote process group.  Yours is 8443.  Test with telnet from minifi to nifi port 8443.

Comment: I cannot telnet 8443 from minifi instance, it is blocked by the firewall. I need to know (or set) the port that minifi uses, in order to configure the firewall, to allow the connexion with the specified port. I cannot find any of this property in the documentation.

Comment: It won't be in nifi documentation, this is just container/server networking.  You need outbound from MiNiFi host to 8443.  Should be a simple firewall rule or command. Once you can see telnet to port work, then nifi is ready.   With nifi being SSL, you may have to work on ssl connection next,